# Is Jsoup can be available for Xamarin or Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, jsoup, xamarin.forms

Please confirm me if Jsoup is available to use in Xamarin.Forms.

I am trying to get the app version from play store.

I tried but failed.

Could you please provide me with suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to provide evidence that you've search something, this seems that you want the job done, instead of googling it. Don't wait for someone to do your job.

Comment: i got Jsoup.dll from Jsoup.jar by using Bindings Librabary(Android) template. but I am unable to use Jsoup library in my xamarin.forms  project.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use .net based library such as [AngleSharp](https://github.com/FlorianRappl/AngleSharp) ? It's a portable class library and has supports for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS

Answer (score 0):

It seems it can actually be done. Xamarin offers tools to do so. Keep in mind it only works with Android, though, not with iOS or Windows.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/

Answer (score 0):

I've ported Jsoup to support to Xamarin.Android. You can get the [library here](https://github.com/nitinwagadia/Xamarin.Android-Jsoup) 
 
I know this is late but may help someone who is looking for it.